# SQL Server 2008 -Joining on Max Values on Multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the below two tables.

```
a.id    a.UpdateDate    a.O    a.1     b.id    b.UpdateDate  b.0   b.1
  1        1/1/15        a      b         1         2/1/15    a     b
  1        1/1/15        c      d         1         3/1/15    a     c
  1        5/1/15        e      f         1         3/1/15    d     e
```

I would like to see one row per Id. The lastest Update Date for Table a The Latest Updatedate for table b then join those two tables on Id. That way I'm getting the most recent Updates from both tables with one row per id.

```
a.id    a.UpdateDate   b.id    b.UpdateDate  a.o   a.1   b.0   b.1
  1        5/1/15       1         3/1/15      e     f     d     e
```

I want the max values for both tables and struggling on next steps. 
EDIT --I need the latest UpdateDate and id (1 row Per id) for both tables, then I would like to join table a and b to id.

```
Select a.id, a.UpdateDate, b.id, b.UpdateDate  
From a
  inner join (select id, max(UpdateDate) AS dt From a group by id) 
   maxdt On A.id = maxdt.id and a.UpdateDate = maxdt.UpdateDate
```

The above solves extracting the max UpdateDate from table a. Now how would I extract the max UpdateDate from table b? I hope that this is clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY updateDate DESC) rn
        FROM    a
        GROUP BY
                id
        ) ag
JOIN    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY updateDate DESC) rn
        FROM    b
        GROUP BY
                id
        ) bg
ON      bg.id = ag.id
WHERE   ag.rn = 1
        AND bg.rn = 1
```

Comment: Quassnoi - Not sure this is going to work. If I want to add a column from Table A or B I would have to add those columns into the inner select and group by, correct? I'm trying to avoid doing this and I have captured the first piece above to where I have self joined. I was hoping I could do this with table B too.

Comment: @mrjohn: why would you need to add the other columns to select and group by? There is only id and max date in the resultset you're after

Comment: There are additioanl columns that need to be added. I have about 40 columns.

Comment: @MrJohn: could you please update your post and specify what the resultset should look like?

Comment: I have updates my question The main piece is... I would like to see one row per Id. The lastest Update Date for Table a The Latest Updatedate for table b then join those two tables on Id. That way I'm getting the most recent Updates from both tables with one row per id.

Comment: For table A I have what I need based on my query above, for me it's adding table B that I'm having trouble with. I'm trying to use a CTE - With Statement or was thinking about some sort of ranking.

Comment: @MrJohn: did you try my answer?